How can I count the query parameters in URL in APIM policy?
I am trying to find an approach on how to prevent API in APIM to allows only 2 specific query parameters. One thing I came up with is to use C# in a policy expression to count the query parameters that the API request contains. Can someone help me with that?
I tried using that:

However it errors out:
Error in element 'set-variable' on line 20, column 18: The type or namespace name 'HttpUtility' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Import System.Web

You can use the given policy to count the specific query parameters.
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-variable name="queryParamCount" value="@(context.Request.Url.Query.Count())" />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.Url.Query.ContainsKey(&quot;param1&quot;) && context.Request.Url.Query.ContainsKey(&quot;param2&quot;) && context.Request.Url.Query.Count() == 2)">
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <return-response>
                    <set-status code="400" reason="Bad Request" />
                    <set-body>Only 'param1' and 'param2' are allowed as query parameters.</set-body>
                </return-response>
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
    </inbound>
</policies>

You can get the below errors if you try to pass one or three query parameters or parameter with different name.



It will only accept param1 and param2 as query parameter.



